# Foreign Keys pointing to same Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have an `User` model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name

  has_many :client_workouts
end
```

And a `ClientWorkout` model

```
class ClientWorkout < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :client_id, :trainer_id, :workout_id

  belongs_to :client, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => 'client_id'

  belongs_to :trainer, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => 'trainer_id'  
end
```

I first want to know what or if I'm doing something wrong when writing the associations. Ideally I want to be able to call a query where I find the user's clients workouts where the user's id matches with `client_id` or `trainer_id`. So...

```
user.client_workouts.trainer???
```

Comment: It looks fine to me. You should just be able to call `client_workout.client.email` or `client_workout.trainer.email` due to your `belongs_to` relationship. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: Yeah you're right. I was doing something silly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work as rails assumes that the ClientWorkout have a `user_id` column. I don't think there is any way to make a has_many relation that matches two columns... Instead you could create a method like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name

  has_many :client_workouts, :foreign_key => "client_id"

  has_many :trainer_workouts, :foreign_key => "trainer_id"

  def client_and_trainer_workouts
    ClientWorkouts.where("client_id = ? OR trainer_id = ?", id, id)
  end
end
```

Otherwise you could create a scope on the ClientWorkout model like this:

```
class ClientWorkout < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :client_id, :trainer_id, :workout_id

  belongs_to :client, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => 'client_id'

  belongs_to :trainer, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => 'trainer_id'  

  scope :workouts_for_user, 
      lambda {|user| where("client_id = ? OR trainer_id = ?", user.id, user.id) }
end
```

You could also do both, and let the method on the use call the scope on the ClientWorkout.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there would be some trick I missed but alas there is not.